# Passing a value through Button to Php function

Tags: php

[image]

I am beginner in php and I am currently working on admin panel (you can see my admin panel page). The thing is that I want to pass serial number through these two buttons to perform further. But I can't find how to send `$value` to edit and delete a particular line.

```
<div id="headin2"><strong> <h3>Admin page </h3></strong></div>
<?php 
    echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" id=\"tab\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th id=\"td1\">Serial No</th><th id=\"td2\">Account Title</th>
              <th id=\"td3\">Email</th><th id=\"td4\">Gender</th><th id=\"td5\">city</th>
              <th id=\"td6\">Course</th><th id=\"td7\">status</th><th id=\"td8\" colspan=\"3\">Action</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $SN = $row['SN'];
        $actitle = $row['ac_title']; 
        $email = $row['email'];
        $gender  = $row['sex']; 
        $cite = $row['city'];
        $course = $row['CRS'];
        $status  = $row['status'];  

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$SN."</td><td>".$actitle."</td><td>".$email."</td>
                  <td>".$gender."</td><td>".$cite."</td><td>".$course."</td><td>".$status."</td>
                  <td>"."<input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\"/>
                  <input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"delete\" >"."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Show us your code of the two buttons you have so far.

Comment: thing is I cannnot find how to procedd

Comment: But what have you so far? At least the HTML markup you've written. So show it to us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need both the `action` (edit/delete) **and** the row `id`. Unfortunately, without some JS the button will only post one value.

You can create a new form for each row, add in a hidden element. For example:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) : ?>

  <tr>
    <!-- other cells -->
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Update"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Then after posting it you can just check for the `action` and `id`

```
if ($_POST['action'] && $_POST['id']) {
  if ($_POST['action'] == 'Edit') {
    // edit the post with $_POST['id']
  }
}
```

Comment: You made my work very simple ! Thank you very much AlexP :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it one of two ways.

### jQuery and AJAX

For each `<tr>`, everywhere there is a delete button,

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $value; ?>" class="delete-row">Delete</a>
```

Script at the bottom:

```
//Include jQuery here
<script language="javascript">
$('.delete-row').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   $.ajax({
      url: "url/to/delete",
      method: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data: { id: id },
      success: function (html) {
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

This puts the ID of the row into the `<a href>` itself using `data` and uses jQuery to send out an AJAX call to delete the record. If the delete is successful, it removes the row from the table.

### Old-School Button

For each `<tr>`, everywhere there is a Delete button,

```
<form method="POST" action="url/to/delete">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

This is the old-school way to do it, where the hidden field is how the backend knows which row to delete.

On the backend, you still use `$_POST['id'];` to get the ID of the record to remove. In the above examples, `$value` is the ID for each row, and is most likely something like `$row['id']` when it is coming from a `foreach()`.

Comment: Aww God bless You got that Thankx:)

Answer (score 3):

Use a hidden input (e.g.`<input type="hidden" value="your_value_here">`)

Answer (score 3):

when you click Edit it open a page with corresponding record. You can do it by a Edit link or a image or a button.

```
<?php echo "<a href='".BASE_URL."admin/edit.php?id=$id' target='_blank'> <img src=".BASE_URL."/images/edit.png width=16 height=16 alt=Edit /> </a>";?>
```

for delete you can use jquery. here is a example

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='deletePrescription($id)' ><img src=images/document_delete.png width=16 height=16 title='Delete Prescription' alt=Delete /> </a>";    
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletePrescription(checkup_id) {
//alert(checkup_id);                
var agree=confirm("Do you really want to delete the prescription?");
    if (agree)
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_prescription_admin.php",
                data: "checkup_id="+checkup_id,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                //
                //alert( "array Updated: " + msg );
                location.reload(true);
                }
            });

        }
    else
        {
        return false ;
        }

      }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is on the server side, so you need to send parameters, parse it and have your php act.
i.e.

The edit button will make POST or GET request with parameter: id=123&action=edit

and your PHP will parse the Query String:

```
$strID = $_GET['id'];
$strAction = $_GET['action'];
```

then act on it..

```
if ($strAction=='edit'){
 // do something...
}
```

Your buttons should be wrappen in a form like:

```
<form action="yourFile.php?id=<?=$SN ?>&action=edit" method="GET" id="formEdit<?=$SN ?>">
    <button type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thankx for replying Let me check that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href=register_course.php?id=$roll&code=".$row['course_code']."&name=".$row['course_name']."><input type=submit value=Register>
```

*here register_course.php is the file where you are sending some variable having some data it will be delivered when button is clicked whose value is register //course code is the variable you want to send ... im assigning its value as $ code... and assigning id $roll as id and assigning course_name as $name....

the other file will get the variables having some data

Comment: Sorry but I think that the questions is totally unclear. Please try to form it mor understandable. BTW, if you want to post (submit) data to `register_course.php` , then what is the use of the un-closed `<a` tag?

Comment: trying to answer the question asked above.... this is the first fist time guide me how to do it\