# Passing a variable inside a button in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a variable in a back button, I'm trying to pass back the value from the previous form. Is the format I use correct to pass a variable inside a button in **PHP**?

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        strval($id);

        echo "<a name='btn_edit' href=\"view_order.php?id='$id'\">Back</a>";
    }
?>
```

is this the correct format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a value through Button to Php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814082/passing-a-value-through-button-to-php-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<a name='btn_edit' href=\"view_order.php?id={$id}\">Back</a>";
```